# CakePHP returns all data values as data type string

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

When I do a var_dump immediately after a find in CakePHP, all the field values are listed as having a data type of strings, despite the fields in the database being integers, floats, booleans, or whatever else that's not a string.  Should it be this way, or have I done something wrong in CakePHP, the configuration, or the database driver?  I'm working on an application written in CakePHP version 1.3 with the mysqli driver (the mysql driver behaves the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To be expected

CakePHP only returns what the underlying driver returns, as such it is Db-dependent, but if you're observing all values are strings then yes, it should be that way.

For example, using [the mysql driver](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php#L768-L786) results are always returned as strings:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");

$resource = mysql_query("select * from cakephp.posts");

$myrow = mysql_fetch_row($resource);
var_dump($myrow);
```

Results in:

```
array(5) {
  [0] => string(1) "1" # <- autoincrement int primary key value
  [1] => string(9) "The title"
  [2] => string(22) "This is the post body."
  [3] => string(19) "2013-08-01 07:34:57"
  [4] => string(19) "2013-08-01 07:34:57"
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason I expected it to use the schema definition to type the fields.  perhaps I had read that about a future version of CakePHP?

Comment: 3.x will do that, but not earlier versions.

Comment: ah, good to hear.  yet another reason to upgrade. thanks for the answer.